# How can I convert Uri's in List<string> to List<Uri>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm using ASP.NET Web API with Code First where I have a model called profile which is supposed to hold data as such:

- string Reference (XXX-12345)
- string FirstName (John)
- string LastName  (Doe)
- string Telephone (+xxx xxxxxxxxxx)
- string Email     (john@doe.com)
- string Link      (http://my.api.com/controller/XXX-12345)

I would like to do something like this:

```
List<Uri> ProfileUris = DBContext.Profiles.Select(p => new Uri(p.Link)).ToList()
```

The above throws an error

Any ideas how I can do this conversion without a for loops.

Comment: What error? That piece of code should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entity Framework cannot translate Uri creation into SQL code. Select link column from database, then move processing to client with `AsEnumerable()` call - that will allow you to call C# code without trying to convert it to SQL:

```
List<Uri> ProfileUris = DBContext.Profiles.Select(p => p.Link)
                                 .AsEnumerable()
                                 .Select(l => new Uri(l))
                                 .ToList();
```

Comment: An alternative, of course, could be `DBContext.Profiles.AsEnumerable().Select(p => new Uri(p.Link)).ToList();` but it could be more efficient to do it your way (one Select with Linq-to-Sql, and one Select with Linq-to-Objects).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen if you will not project data on server-side, then EF will query for all columns from table in database, then it will map each row in result set to `Profile` entity instance. That is definitely less efficient then returning single column without any mapping :)

Comment: @Sergey: Thanks Sergey! Your code was the answer that led me to a little refactored as follows: List<Uri> ProfileUris = DBContext.Profiles.AsEnumerable().Select(l => new Uri(l)).ToList(); It gets rid of the extra 'Select'

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: I just realised....my refactoring ended up the same as your answer.